# Tizen doesn't recognize Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tizen, tizen-web-simulator

I just bought a Samsung gear 2 neo and wanted to create my own watch. So this means I am new to Tizen development.
I installed the Tizen IDE and the SDK but for some reason after following -a part- this tutorial (http://www.slideshare.net/badaindonesia/professional-tizen-application-development) Tizen won't run my projects because it can't find Google Chrome on the specified location. This problem occures when I try to run a Tizen web application as a Tizen web simulator app. When i try to launch it as a Tizen web app it says `Could not find emulator or device` but that isn't my current target.

The specific message is `Google Chrome could not be found (C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe).  Please install Google Chrome and specify the Google Chrome program location in Window->Preferences under "Tizen SDK/Web/Simulator".`

I have tried changing the location to `C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\` But this wouldn't help either. Yes, i have entered the correct location since i have manually located the chrome.exe to.

The only thing which might be wrong is that I am using the Windows 7 64 bit installer while I am on a Windows 8 64 bit desktop pc.

Comment: Try with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

Comment: Do you mean no caps on the chrome.exe part?
I'll try it this evening ;)

Comment: No (path names are case-insensitive in Windows), `Chrome` folder after `Application` in the path.

Comment: Ohh my bad, I did actually use that path to chrome, typo in the question, sorry. -> edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar bug. Maybe this will help you/future developers:

My problem was that the Chrome app wouldn't open while pressing debug. I subsequently tried it with the Visual Studio Tizen extension: same problem.

The fix: I dove into the extension code and found that changing the chrome path via the option "Change Chrome path" doesn't actually change your chrome path.

What does? Going into "*C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.vscode\extensions\tizenweb.wappl-1.1.2\lib\constants.js*" and changing `Constants.CHROME_PATH` to your chrome path (for the operating system you are using).

I have not found a solution for the Tizen app, though I would recommend using the VScode extension anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Though not exactly a solution, I found a workaround.

1. Start the **Web Simulator** from **Start Menu**
2. Enter the location of your **index.html** file in the **address field** and press **Enter**
3. Don't forget to add ***file:///*** in the front.

There you go!!

Comment: Somehow I can't even open the web simulator itself, system still can't find the right path to Chrome (image is in Dutch -> http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9044/ynidE4.png)